# xtrlock with live Ubuntu and no password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, liveusb

I'm using a live USB with lubuntu to copy between external ext4 drives and wanted to try xtrlock so the 6+ hours process is not interrupted by my cats. But now can't unlock! I type no pass at all in the live session even when sudoing, so I'm puzzled. Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: i have installed `xtrlock` on my system , i can switch to the tty then `killall xtrlock` to unlock the keyboard and the mouse

Comment: sneaky! make it an answer and I'll choose it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to the TTY then run:

```
sudo killall xtrlock
```

Comment: You might add a little context explaining what this does to help ensure the OP understands the detail at this level.

Comment: It just kills the process.